# Can the word "opportunity" be used as a non-countable noun?

Tags: nouns

Can the word "opportunity" be used as a non-countable noun? Can I say "a lot of opportunity" like in "a lot of exposure" or "a lot of pressure"?

Comment: I don't disagree with Kevin's answer, but it's worth noting that NGrams records 80,000 instances of *"a lot of opportunity"*, against 130,000 for [a lot of opportunities](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+lot+of+opportunity%2Ca+lot+of+opportunities&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3). Obviously *"opportunity"* can be either countable or not, according to personal preference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You *can* but I would prefer to use "plenty of" instead - as in "he had plenty of opportunity to stop, but continued regardless". Both "a lot of" and "plenty of" work grammatically though.